# Random number repeating in Lua

Tags: lua

Am new to Lua and am planning to develop Bingo game.
I have created 25 grids and i have generated numbers randomly.
But the numbers in grid is repeating 
I have searched but i couldn't found kindly help me friends.

```
--enter code here
local widget = require "widget"
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local xaxis = {40,80,120,160,200,40,80,120,160,200,40,80,120,160,200,40,80,120,160,200,40,80,120,160,200}
local yaxis = {40,40,40,40,40,80,80,80,80,80,120,120,120,120,120,160,160,160,160,160,200,200,200,200,200}
local img = {}
local i
local k
local u={}
    for i = 1, 25 do
        img[i] = display.newImageRect( "t.png", 39, 39 )
        img[i].x=xaxis[i]
        img[i].y=yaxis[i]
        math.randomseed( os.time() )
        j = math.random(1,75)
        u[i], u[j] = u[j], u[i]
        img[i] = display.newText(j,0,0,native.systemFont,20)
        img[i].x=xaxis[i]
        img[i].y=yaxis[i]  
    end
```

The numbers is generating randomly but the number is repeating

Answer (score 3):

This is common mistake almost in every programming language. When you use random in loop you should always assign time seed outside of loop. Because iterations are really fast and it every-time re-assigns current time that results in the same *random* number generation.

So all you have to do is to take `math.randomseed( os.time() )` out of loop:

```
math.randomseed( os.time() )

for i = 1, 25 do
    img[i] = display.newImageRect( "t.png", 39, 39 )
    img[i].x=xaxis[i]
    img[i].y=yaxis[i]
    j = math.random(1,75)
    u[i], u[j] = u[j], u[i]
    img[i] = display.newText(j,0,0,native.systemFont,20)
    img[i].x=xaxis[i]
    img[i].y=yaxis[i]  
end
```

[Proof](http://ideone.com/elAjXi).

Comment: Even though the numbers getting repeated kindly help me friend

Comment: @MaheshJayachandran Numbers will and should repeat. If you are looking for shuffle algorithm take a look at modern version of [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modern_method).